# value not sending with <select> <options>

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

```
$clients = $this->requestAction('/clients/get_names');

$client_array = array();

foreach ($clients as $client) {
$client_array[$client['Client']['client_name']] = $client['Client']['client_name'];
    }
    echo $this->Form->input('title', array(
        'name' => 'title',
        'options' => $client_array,
        'empty' => 'Select a client',
        'label' => ''
    ));
```

HTML OUTPUT

```
<select name="title" id="title">
<option value="">Select a client</option>
<option value="Jennifer Lopez">Jennifer Lopez</option>
</select>
```

ON CLICK SUBMIT IT SEND DATA TO MY JS FILE

```
      $.post( "save",
      { action: "save",
      start: calEvent.start.getTime()/1000,
      end: calEvent.end.getTime()/1000,
      title: calEvent.title,
      body: calEvent.body,
              id: calEvent.id
});
```

RECIEVE THE DATA AND PUT IN DATABASE

```
public function save() {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';

    $title = $_REQUEST['title']; // tried $this->request->data allready
    $body = $_REQUEST['body'];
    $start_time = (int)$_REQUEST['start'];
    $start_time = $start_time + 60*60;
    $end_time = (int)$_REQUEST['end'];
    $end_time = $end_time + 60*60;
    $start = date('c',$start_time);
    $end = date('c',$end_time);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO agendas (title,body,start,end) VALUES ('$title','$body','$start','$end')";
    $this->Agenda->query($sql);
    exit(0);
}
```

**Now the problem is when select "Jennifer Lopez", it wont send the value with the form.**

**So in this case it wont post "Jennifer Lopez", in to my database. How to send the selection with form?**

I'm a beginner so i'm in learning mode!

Comment: I said this on your last post, you need to find the `list` type, specify the field you want in your list (key will be the primary key), and in your save function, you use `$_POST` to access it.

Comment: I see no code where you reference the SELECT box value at all.

Comment: Can you give the code for the Model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure `title: calEvent.title` is being sent in the AJAX Post? Double check that part. It could be that your jQuery selector for `calEvent.title` is wrong.